# Iterator vs. Adaptor design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, iterator, adaptor

I am new to design patterns and lately I started reading Head First Design Patterns.

It seems to me that the *Iterator* design pattern is really similar to the *Adaptor* design pattern. I know that the *Adaptor* pattern creates an adaptor that helps codes A and B communicate while the client only interacts with the interface of code A.

 I find the *Iterator* pattern really similar to that, especially in the example of the diner and the pancake house merging.[You can check the example here.](http://csc.columbusstate.edu/woolbright/java/iterator.htm)

**So here is my question, is *Iterator* pattern a form of the *Adaptor* pattern?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different patterns. Adapter is a *Structural Pattern* while Iterator is a *Behavioral Pattern*.

**Adapter**:-
Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.

**Iterator**: 
Provide a way to access the elements of an aggregate object sequentially without exposing its underlying representation.

Reference: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx